# How to add negative assertions like not.toHaveText in Detox?

Tags: react-native, testing, e2e-testing, detox

I need to set negation for some text content and tried the code below but as it isn't stated in the docs I expected it to fail and it sure did, so I would like to know how could I possibly achieve negation in this case.

`await expect(element(by.id('myElemId'))).not.toHaveText('some text')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don' think Detox has the ability to use the `.not` property of `expect`

However you could so something like this:

First create a function that returns a boolean if a specific text phrase exists. We use the fact that if a value doesn't exist it will throw and error, by wrapping it in a `try/catch` we can return a boolean that we can then use in our tests.

```
async function hasText (id, text) {
  try {
    await expect(element(by.id(id))).toHaveText(text);
    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

You can then use it in the following way throwing an error if it returns true for having the text.

```
it('should not have some text', async () => {
  await expect(element(by.id('myElemId'))).toBeVisible();
  let result = await hasText('myElemId', 'some text');
  // so if the text exists it will return true, as we don't want it to exist then we can throw our own error.
  if (result) {
    throw new Error('Should not have some text, but did.');
  }
});
```

I know that this is not an elegant solution to the problem, and it would be much nicer if Detox gave us the APIs we needed but I suppose that this could be used in a pinch.

Comment: Andrew, first of all, I want to thank you for helping Rainyer. Also, your answer is very important. Could someone of you guys check if this feature request exists in Detox Github Issues? If not, could you please do, that, Andrew, Rainyer?

Comment: Sorry for late response. As this feature does not exist in the lib, your solution makes total sense to me and I can easily import it as an utility function in whatever test file I need, thank you very much for taking some time to help @Andrew.

Comment: @noomorph I would be glad to open a feature request in the Detox repo for that as this thing looks like a very handy capability to the lib api.

Answer (score 2):

As of Detox version 17.11.4 you can do this

```
await expect(element(by.id(options.testID))).toBeNotVisible()
```

or

```
await expect(element(by.text(options.text))).toBeNotVisible()
```

This is the correct way to do it using the recommended setup with Jest.